# How to back-up a folder every 15 minutes without taking up more space than needed?

Tags: backup, storage, data-transfer, duplicity, workflow

I'm incrementally backing up my coding project with Duplicity and am finding it's consuming storage faster than expected.

The folder I'm backing up consists mostly of gifs, images, and libraries that take up most of the space and are only occasionally changed, and my script files which take up very little space but need to be backed up every 15 minutes or so to avoid losing hours of progress if data is accidentally deleted.

Since Duplicity doesn't store the files whole but has encrypted slices that need to be restored, I assumed that means it's only copying the parts of the folders that need to be changed into a snapshot and algorithmically piecing it together?

If not, is there a tool that would be more efficient for doing this? Ideally I'm trying to set up a system that backs up the entire folder to a USB drive once per day, and does a more efficient sync every 15 minutes so I can easily go back if I accidentally delete everything.

Comment: You could use git for that purpose and create a bare repo on the USB Stick. Diff handling and file data deduplication is built-in. To avoid an ever growing repo start a new repo e.g. once a day. Alternatively you could try a backup tool like [restic](https://restic.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use robocopy.
Ex. Robocopy "C:\path\tofolder"  "U:\path\toUSB" /MIR

Then use task scheduler to run this as often as needed. There are some other useful switches that you could enable, as well.

Comment: I was just about to use Robocopy, but reading the documentation found this. My files are open 24/7 so it's important that I can copy it while it's open.

"There are some drawbacks about Robocopy, of course. It cannot copy open files or live operating system volume; The operation isn’t intuitive enough for users who are used to GUI software; And most of all, Robocopy won’t keep different versions of the source data nor provide image recovery."

Comment: Robocopy is great for backing up folders containing coding projects, I've used it with success for quite some time. Your text files for your coding project will back up fine as they're read into memory,  not actually "open". They only are while 'actively' being written to disk, for instance a save. Of course I could be mis understanding your situation and I apologize if so. Great thing is that you can always give a try, the scripts are very short. For instance if you have the space you can just robocopy the whole project directory while you are coding and see how it works for you.

Comment: I'd like to also add that I employ the use of the /R and /W switch. This option tells robocopy how many times to retry. This will catch any issues in the off chance the file is actively being saved during a copy. You can adjust how many retries with /R and adjust wait time with /W.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. Because I was going to say I use auto-save on VS Code so it saves pretty much constantly when I'm typing/editing. So I'll definitely set the retry attempts to a high number. Thanks for the info. Sounds like that would work perfectly then for what I need. When I was researching I read a lot of people suggesting not to use Robocopy but they never expalined why. So I tried some other tools but looks like Robocopy is the standard that most people use.

Comment: If you found this answer and comment thread useful, please upvote :)